# How to list available ViewSet actions in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've added a custom action to a Viewset, via "@detail_route". Is there some way to list any custom actions?

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def my_action(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

What I would like to happen (e.g.):

```
curl 127.0.0.1/api/whatever/1/?format=json
>>> {'actions':{'my_action':'/api/whatever/1/my_action'},...}
```

Like-wise, does the API format have a mechanism to display that information?

Answer (score 0):

By doing an authenticated `OPTIONS` call, it's possible to return `PUT` and `POST` actions by default:

```
curl -X OPTIONS --user username:password 127.0.0.1/api/whatever/1/?format=json
```

Comment: is it possible to customize this OPTIONS response?